# Interactive shell based on SSH and UDP

Tags: linux, ssh, unix, udp

I've heard from a friend about a client-server application which initializes on top of SSH connection but implements interactive shell over UDP protocol. It is specifically designed for bad quality connection and keeping terminal responsive and avoiding disconnects.

Unfortunately I don't remember the name of the application. Is there anything like this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think that you may be looking for [Mosh](http://mosh.mit.edu/), the Mobile Shell

Comment: Bingo. http://mosh.mit.edu